# Where will I find WOW64... defines on my setup (VS 2005 on Vista 64, C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, vista64

I got a project from the web. The "solution" and the "projects" files were coded for VS2010 but I changed the version numbers and I could load them in my VS2005. I tried to build the solution and I get errors like:

```
'WOW64_CONTEXT': undeclared identifier
'wow64Context': undeclared identifier
'Wow64GetThreadContext': is not a member of 'global namespace'
etc...
```

I know from the doc that **WOW64_CONTEXT** must be declared inside winnt.h. On my system, it is not. What is going on? I'm new to WoW but I understand the concept. I just never used it.

Here is my setup (*NOTE: I have Intel CC 9 installed but I don't use it for this project. I use the MS compiler*):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
Version 8.0.50727.867  (vsvista.050727-8600)
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 2.0.50727 SP2

Installed Edition: Professional
Microsoft Visual C# 2005   77626-009-2220332-41593
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005   77626-009-2220332-41593
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Applications   77626-009-2220332-41593
Microsoft Web Application Projects 2005   77626-009-2220332-41593
Version 8.0.50727.867
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB932372)

Intel(R) C++ Compiler Integration for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005, Version 9.1.632.2005 , Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Intel Corporation.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB926601)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2251481)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2465367)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2538218)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971023)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971090)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB973673)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - ENU (KB932232)

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The version of the Windows SDK included with VS2005 is badly outdated.  Not sure if the latest SDK (7.1) still supports VS2005, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681670.aspx), see that "Minimum supported client: Vista" section.

You'll need a recent version of the Windows SDK that covers Vista, and also need to define the `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` macros to 0x600 or higher to enable Vista functions.  The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx) and Raymond Chen gives some history [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/11/2079137.aspx).

- [Currently latest Windows SDK download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279)
- [List of Windows SDKs on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) (check here for updated download links)

Comment: Same bug, Ben. The problem is that WOW64_CONTEXT (and other Wow functions) are declared/defined nowhere on my disk. Why? Where should/can I find them? BTW, the values in the current code are WINVER = _WIN32_WINNT = 0x0501, _WIN32IE = 0x0400 and _RICHEDIT_VER = 0x0100. ... No "Wow effect" on me so far ! ;-)

Comment: Since you're trying to use types and functions that didn't even exist in 2005, I assume you've downloaded a newer Platform SDK that covers Vista (and probably Windows 7), such as [the currently latest version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279)?  (Future users, check also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) for updated links)

Comment: Don't assume that! Probablly you gave me the answer! Before getting the latest version and forcing all my colleagues to do the same, I will try to "comment" the code that is using these functions/defines. I can, afterward, assume I won't run on Wow64 for my app.

Comment: @dom_beau: Oh, you will run on WOW64 (I can't remember if VC++ 2005 even had 64-bit compilers), but you don't require any special steps to do so.  Those structures you're talking about are for debugging 32-bit processes from a 64-bit debugger, stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone else will ask this question again, although it was already here even 4 years.

1. Open your C disk. and serch for WinNT.H.
2. Open WinNT.H and serch for CONTEXT_AMD64
3. DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16) _CONTEXT will feed your need.
4. For short: Open WinNT.H and goto line:3647. Ok, got it.

Comment: Thanks! Could be useful somewhere! ;-)